# Watch a variable local (no a la store de vuex)

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Si yo tengo un estado en la tienda de vuex, puedo obtener datos al momento que éste estado cambie, con un `watch` desde algun componente haciendo algo como:

```
const store = useStore()

const observadorDeEstado = computed(() => return store.state.estadoQueQuieroEscuchar) 

watch(observadorDeEstado, (estadoActual, estadoAnterior) => {
    console.log("El valor de la tienda cambio de ",b, " a ",a)
})
```

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Si yo quiero escuchar, en lugar de una variable de la store, una variable local al componente, no sé como hacerlo. Probé con:

```
const variableLocal = ref(null)
const observarLocal = computed(() => return variableLocal.value)
watch(observarLocal, () => {...})
```

y con

```
const variableLocal = ref(null)
watch(variableLocal, () => {...})
```

y nunca obtengo el console.

> La pregunta entonces sería: Como puedo escuchar un cambio sobre una variable local, como lo hago con `watch`y `vuex`?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Después de algunos intentos llegué a una solución. La forma correcta de escuchar una variable local es sin usar una propiedad computada y agregando `.value` luego de la variable a escuchar (esto me confundía ya que tanto una propiedad computada como una variable `ref()` son reactivas, y ambas se acceden a través de `nombre.value`, pero para escuchar una computada no es necesario poner .value, en cambio para una variable reactiva local, sí lo es):

```
const variableLocal = ref(null)
watch(variableLocal.value, () => {...})
```